# To work with older account

Tags: discussion, users

I have a account already on Ubuntu 12.04.Now I shifted to Ubuntu 15.10.That's why I had to create this account.Can't I work with my older account.I know I should ask it on meta but with this new account I don't have enough reputations.

Comment: Does this help? [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @steeldriver,Yes it worked so thaaaaanks a lot.